# issues working with python generators and openstack swift client

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm having a problem with Python generators while working with the Openstack Swift client library.

The problem at hand is that I am trying to retrieve a large string of data from a specific url (about 7MB), chunk the string into smaller bits, and send a generator class back, with each iteration holding a chunked bit of the string. in the test suite, this is just a string that's sent to a monkeypatched class of the swift client for processing.

The code in the monkeypatched class looks like this:

```
def monkeypatch_class(name, bases, namespace):
    '''Guido's monkeypatch metaclass.'''
    assert len(bases) == 1, "Exactly one base class required"
    base = bases[0]
    for name, value in namespace.iteritems():
        if name != "__metaclass__":
            setattr(base, name, value)
    return base
```

And in the test suite:

```
from swiftclient import client
import StringIO
import utils

class Connection(client.Connection):
    __metaclass__ = monkeypatch_class

    def get_object(self, path, obj, resp_chunk_size=None, ...):
        contents = None
        headers = {}

        # retrieve content from path and store it in 'contents'
        ...

        if resp_chunk_size is not None:
            # stream the string into chunks
            def _object_body():
                stream = StringIO.StringIO(contents)
                buf = stream.read(resp_chunk_size)
                while buf:
                    yield buf
                    buf = stream.read(resp_chunk_size)
            contents = _object_body()
        return headers, contents
```

After returning the generator object, it was called by a stream function in the storage class:

```
class SwiftStorage(Storage):

    def get_content(self, path, chunk_size=None):
        path = self._init_path(path)
        try:
            _, obj = self._connection.get_object(
                self._container,
                path,
                resp_chunk_size=chunk_size)
            return obj
        except Exception:
            raise IOError("Could not get content: {}".format(path))

    def stream_read(self, path):
        try:
            return self.get_content(path, chunk_size=self.buffer_size)
        except Exception:
            raise OSError(
                "Could not read content from stream: {}".format(path))
```

And finally, in my test suite:

```
def test_stream(self):
    filename = self.gen_random_string()
    # test 7MB
    content = self.gen_random_string(7 * 1024 * 1024)
    self._storage.stream_write(filename, io)
    io.close()
    # test read / write
    data = ''
    for buf in self._storage.stream_read(filename):
        data += buf
    self.assertEqual(content,
                     data,
                     "stream read failed. output: {}".format(data))
```

The output ends up with this:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_stream (test_swift_storage.TestSwiftStorage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bacongobbler/git/github.com/bacongobbler/docker-registry/test/test_local_storage.py", line 46, in test_stream
    "stream read failed. output: {}".format(data))
AssertionError: stream read failed. output: <generator object _object_body at 0x2a6bd20>
```

I tried isolating this with a simple python script that follows the same flow as the code above, which passed without issues:

```
def gen_num():
    def _object_body():
        for i in range(10000000):
            yield i
    return _object_body()

def get_num():
    return gen_num()

def stream_read():
    return get_num()

def main():
    num = 0
    for i in stream_read():
        num += i
    print num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Should you be returning _object_body in function gen_num? Without the parantheses?

Comment: Something's strange.  Is it the last line in `test_stream` throwing the error message?  If so, it seems like `data` is `<generator object _object_body at 0x2a6bd20>`, but I don't see how that can be.  When did it change from being a string?

Comment: Stick some prints in your code to be sure you're executing what you *think* you're executing.  As @DSM said, `data` started life as a string in the code *you showed* here, and `data += buf` could not change that - it's impossible that `data` magically changed into a generator object in the code *you showed*.  Therefore I conclude ;-) that you're not actually executing the code you showed.

Comment: @DSM, yes, it's the last line in <code>test_stream</code> that's throwing this error message.

Comment: Think of <code>path</code> as the path to a file in a S3 bucket, with <code>contents</code> being the data contained within that file.

I think the problem may have to deal with the code finding a path that returns no content, which then <code>contents</code> will just return None back to <code>stream_read</code>. I still don't understand why a generator class would be returned in that case, however. Maybe an empty file?

Comment: @bacongobbler: you should address the "why is `data` not a string?" question first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `get_object` method, you're assigning the return value of `_object_body()` to the `contents` variable. However, that variable is also the one that holds your actual data, and it's used early on in `_object_body`.

The problem is that `_object_body` is a generator function (it uses `yield`). Therefore, when you call it, it produces a generator object, but *the code of the function doesn't start running until you iterate over that generator*. Which means that when the function's code actually starts running (the `for` loop in `_test_stream`), it's long after you've reassigned `contents = _object_body()`.

Your `stream = StringIO(contents)` therefore creates a `StringIO` object containing the generator object (hence your error message), *not* the data.

Here's a minimal reproduction case that illustrates the problem:

```
def foo():
    contents = "Hello!"

    def bar():
        print contents
        yield 1

    # Only create the generator. This line runs none of the code in bar.
    contents = bar()

    print "About to start running..."
    for i in contents:
        # Now we run the code in bar, but contents is now bound to 
        # the generator object. So this doesn't print "Hello!"
        pass
```

Comment: I think you nailed it! One mistake, here: "creates a StringIO object containing the generator object".  It actually creates a StringIO object containing `str(_object_body())`, which is the string `'<generator object _object_body at 0x2a6bd20>'`.  What a mess ;-)

Comment: Indeed, you're right. So the lesson to take away from that is, don't reuse variables for multiple unrelated things. (I find that I'm more and more programming in single assignment style, precisely to avoid those problems)

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot for everyone's help on this issue :)