# using generators and cStringIO in python to stream strings

Tags: python, cstringio

I'm trying to read a very large string stream using cStringIO in a python dictionary:

```
def stream_read(self, path):
    try:
        # create a string stream from the contents at 'path'
        # note: the string at self._my_dict[path] is 7MB in size
        stream = StringIO.StringIO(self._my_dict[path])
        while True:
            # buffer size is 128kB, or 128 * 1024
            buf = stream.read(self.buffer_size)
            if buf != '':
                yield buf
            else:
                raise StopIteration
    except KeyError:
        raise IOError("Could not get content")
```

And in my test suite, I'm testing this function by first testing stream_write, asserting that the data exists at that path, and then calling stream_read:

```
def test_stream(self):
    filename = self.gen_random_string()
    # test 7MB
    content = self.gen_random_string(7 * 1024 * 1024)
    # test stream write
    io = StringIO.StringIO(content)
    self._storage.stream_write(filename, io)
    io.close()
    self.assertTrue(self._storage.exists(filename))
    # test read / write
    data = ''
    for buf in self._storage.stream_read(filename):
        data += buf
    self.assertEqual(content, data)
```

Yet in my test suite, I'm catching an AssertionError:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_stream (test_swift_storage.TestSwiftStorage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bacongobbler/.../test/test_local_storage.py", line 44, in test_stream
    self.assertEqual(content, data)
AssertionError: '[squelched]' != '<cStringIO.StringI object at 0x3148e70>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 28 tests in 20.495s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It looks related to [an issue I posted last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429971/issues-working-with-python-generators-and-openstack-swift-client), but I'm still not quite sure I understand why `stream` is getting set to the Generator as a string in this case.

If anyone wants to take a closer look at the source code, it's all up at https://github.com/bacongobbler/docker-registry/blob/106-swift-storage/test/utils/mock_swift_storage.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store *just* the `StringIO` object when calling `self._storage.stream_write(filename, io)`:

```
def put_content(self, path, content, chunk=None):
    path = self._init_path(path)
    try:
        self._swift_container[path] = content
    except Exception:
        raise IOError("Could not put content")
```

where `content` is the `io` object you passed in.

Later on, you pass that file object to `StringIO` again:

```
stream = StringIO.StringIO(self.get_content(path))
```

This calls `str()` on `self.get_content(path)`, storing the string representation of a `cStringIO.StringI()` instance:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> str(StringIO('test data'))
'<cStringIO.StringI object at 0x1074ea470>'
```

Your *reading* code works fine, it is your writing mock that needs to actually take the data *out* of the `StringIO` object.

A `.read()` call will do here:

```
def put_content(self, path, content, chunk=None):
    path = self._init_path(path)
    try:
        self._swift_container[path] = content.read()
    except Exception:
        raise IOError("Could not put content")
```

Comment: Herp derp, I missed that one. Good catch!